# save javascript .replace regex $1 and $2 as javascript variables

Tags: javascript, regex

Im having issues with a multiple video encoder. Im trying to save the embed urls as variables to be used at a later time.

The encoder takes a videos information from a div with text.

```
<div class="text">hey check this video out! youtube.com/watch?v=123456</div>

$('.text').html(function(i, html) {
var videoAddress = html.replace(/(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.*?)([^\s]+)/g, '$2').replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(.+)/g, '$1');
});
```

My desired output would be:

```
var embedCode = [Either $1 or $2];
```

I've looked everywhere with no solution. Is this possible with regex and javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it like this:

```
var arr = [];
var str = "hey check this video out! youtube.com/watch?v=123456 and there is some other text youtube.com/watch?v=3t_3456 and some more.";
var re = /youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^\s]+)/g;
while (match = re.exec(str)) {
  arr.push(match[1]);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: I should have clarified it better. What I meant was If the embed code was in a div ex. (hey check this video out! youtube.com/watch?v=123456)

Comment: so you can have multiple links throughout the div along with random text , right ?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what im trying to do

Comment: How is this line "while (match = re.exec(str)) {" a valid statement you are assigning to a variable in a while condition? should I put === instead? @aelor

Comment: @vigneshsivakumar No, its not what you think it is. The equal actually assigns the value of the `re.exec(str)` to match, whose second element is the matched data. On repeating the `re.exec(str)` the subsequent matches are found